# Test for non-normal data with homogeneity of variance

Tags: distributions, anova, heteroscedasticity, kruskal-wallis-test, levenes-test

I'm new to the platform and would like the following question to be answered:

I have performed a latent class cluster analysis with 28 variables and 9000 observations, for which I am currently performing a post-hoc analysis on.

All the variables are non-normal. I first performed the Levene's test, for which all but one variable do not have equal population variances. And then I wanted to perform an analysis of variance overall and between-groups. For the ones that do have heterogeneity of variance, I performed the Kruskal-Wallis test and subsequently the Mann-Whitney U test.

However, I do not know what my options are regarding the variable 'Age' which has equal population variances. Since the variable also does not follow a normal distribution. Some topics mentioned that it is okay if the distribution deviates a little bit from normal, however the kurtosis is 2.067 and skewness -0.074, which is visualized below. I would like to know if there are other options than the One-way ANOVA and Kruskal-Wallis test suitable here. And is it still accepted to run a Mann-Whitney U test on this variable in order to find differences between groups?

If my way of thinking is incorrect, please feel free to correct me since I am not so experienced in this area. Also, if more data is needed please let me know.

Kind regards

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite following your question...  Are you making an assumption that KW / WMW shouldn't be used with normally-distributed data?

Comment: One comment on post-hoc tests for Kruskal-Wallis (KW).  It is a disadvantage of pairwise Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (WMW) that each test looks at data only from that pair of groups and ignores the rest of the data.  It is better to use a test that retains the ranks from the original KW test.  I recommend Dunn (1964).  There are also Conover test and Nemenyi test.

Comment: If you use such tests on data where the groups are defined by a cluster analysis on the same data, ANOVA, KW and WMW are invalid, because their theory doesn't allow for the groups being constructed in a data dependent way. (Actually I'm not aware of any group comparison test that is valid in such a situation - and there's a good reason for that. Clustering will choose the groups so that they differ as strongly as possible, so the null hypothesis that they are the same doesn't make sense.) Not sure whether I understand everything correctly, but if I do, then these tests do not make sense.

Comment: @salmagniafico Might have phrased my question poorly, did not make the assumption that WMV and KW cannot be used with normal distributed data. I made the assumption that a 1way Anova cannot be used with such data. And since the Age variable variances are equal KW could not be used. Thank you however for recommending the Dunn test, which I will take a look into.

Comment: @Lewian Thank you that does make sense. However, is it wrong to want to prove statistically that each group is different from each other as a post hoc analysis? And would you recommend any other test?

Comment: @jmutr , "And since the Age variable variances are equal KW could not be used".  That's not true. KW / WMW does not make any assumptions about the distribution of the data, including homogeneity of variance.

Comment: @jmutr: "Is it wrong to want to prove statistically that each group is different from each other as a post hoc analysis?" They're automatically different because of the way how they're created. "And would you recommend any other test?" I don't know what your research aim is, no idea.